# Xcode 6 or iOS 8 Bug: UIAlertController Not Showing Message?

Tags: swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

In my view controller I have the following code to create a `UIAlertController`:

```
 var avc = UIAlertController(title: "Location", message: "Please Enter A Location", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            self.navigationController!.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Running it in the simulator, I see

[image]

Pretty sure this is a bug in Xcode 6 beta 7 or swift? Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer, I'm supposed to add an action to the `UIAlertController` for the message to be displayed:

```
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
```

Comment: That seems like a bug. I'd file a report.